# How do I access UEFI SMBIOS table from Linux kernel space?

Tags: linux-kernel, uefi

I want to write a Linux kernel module that do stuff depending on the board vendor and product version.

In userspace, I could just read files under `/sys/class/dmi/id/*`, but they are not available in kernel space.

I think I should collect data from UEFI SMBIOS table. Can I do it without hardcoding the exact memory address where each vendor uses to save the SMBIOS table?

Comment: Here is DMI API for that. Check, for example, `dmi_first_match()`. The documentation is generated from *Documentation/driver-api/firmware/other_interfaces.rst*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out by myself.

There's a library to access DMI and obtain these information:

```
#include <linux/dmi.h>

const char *board_vendor, *product_version;
board_vendor = dmi_get_system_info(DMI_BOARD_VENDOR);
product_version = dmi_get_system_info(DMI_PRODUCT_VERSION);
```